# how to stop the execution of a foreach loop in ADF when an activity fails

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a scenario where I need to fail the complete pipeline when an activity fails inside the ForEach loop container in ADF V2. Don't want the loop to continue further.

I am using ExecutePipeline to call the pipeline which contain ForEach loop.

Please advice me in doing this.

Thanks,
Nandini

Comment: https://andyleonard.blog/2020/06/one-way-to-break-out-of-an-azure-data-factory-foreach-activity/

Comment: You can force a DIV0 on the expressions to fail the pipeline.

Comment: Is this a conditional judgment of whether the activity fails or it is not the expected failure? In other word, whether it succeeds is unpredictable?

Answer (score 4):

In ADF, break loop in the ForEach activity is not supported now. You can add a If Condition activity in the ForEach activity to skip some steps in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

For a situation where I wanted to break out of a loop and return to the parent flow when a Copy data Activity failed, I set the Copy data failure output path to execute two activities:

- Set a condition that would stop looping (in my case # records written less than expected).
- Force a failure with an invalid 'Set variable' (Set a string value to integer or anything that would trigger a fail).

When the Copy data activity fails, execution picks up in the parent flow on the Failure path of the loop.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on the two activities which you set to execute when main activity inside the for each loop fails? Thanks.